# Static Routes between two routers

Tags: routing, vlan

I've currently at a bit of a roadblock.  The scenario is i have two sites approx 5km apart. Each site consists of multiple levels, now i have set up VLANS at both sites, and each PC can ping each other if they're at the same site, but unable to ping a PC from a different site.  In packet tracer i have a 2620 and 2621 Routers for each site, but can't for the life of me, set up a route between the two routers

2621 Router

Fa0/0 - 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.128
Se1/0 - 172.16.4.1

2620 Router

Fa0/0 - 172.16.5.1 255.255.255.128
Se1/0 - 172.16.4.129

Both Routers have the same VLAN config table

FastEthernet0/0.2      172.16.0.129
FastEthernet0/0.3      172.16.1.1
FastEthernet0/0.4      172.16.1.129
FastEthernet0/0.5      172.16.2.1
FastEthernet0/0.6      172.16.2.129
FastEthernet0/0.7      172.16.3.1
FastEthernet0/0.8      172.16.3.129
FastEthernet0/0.9      172.16.5.129
FastEthernet0/0.10     172.16.6.1
FastEthernet0/0.11     172.16.6.129
FastEthernet0/0.12     172.16.7.1
FastEthernet0/0.13     172.16.7.129
FastEthernet0/0.14     172.16.8.1
FastEthernet0/0.15     172.16.8.129
FastEthernet0/0.16     172.16.9.1
FastEthernet0/0.17     172.16.9.129
FastEthernet0/0.18     172.16.10.1

Comment: Please add the actual configurations of both instead of this summary.

Comment: Don't need actual configurations here boss.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've configured the same subnets at each site across a routed link/interface?  Looks like you [think that you] want to bridge the traffic rather than route it.  If that's the case, you need configure bridging.  [Configuring Transparent Bridging](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ibm-technologies/source-route-transparent-srt-bridging/10676-37.html)

### Bridging

Bridges connect and transfer data between LANs. The following are four kinds of bridging:

#### Transparent bridging -

found primarily in Ethernet environments, and is mostly used to bridge networks which have the same media types. Bridges keep a table of destination addresses and outbound interfaces.

#### Source-Route Bridging (SRB) -

found primarily in Token Ring environments. Bridges only forward frames based on the routing indicator contained in the frame. Endstations are responsible for determining and maintaining the table of destination addresses and routing indicators. For more information, refer to Understanding and Troubleshooting Local Source-Route Bridging.

#### Translational bridging -

used to bridge data between different media types. This is typically used to go between Ethernet and FDDI or Token Ring to Ethernet.

#### Source-Route Translational Bridging (SR/TLB) -

a combination of source-route bridging and transparent bridging that allows communication in mixed Ethernet and Token Ring environments. Translational bridging without routing indicators between Token Ring and Ethernet is also called SR/TLB. For more information, refer to Understanding and Troubleshooting Source-Route Translational Bridging.
Bridging happens at the data-link layer, which controls data flow, handles transmission errors, provides physical addressing, and manages access to the physical medium. Bridges analyze incoming frames, make forwarding decisions based on those frames, and forward the frames to their destinations. Sometimes, such as in SRB, the frame contains the entire path to the destination. In other cases, such as in transparent bridging, frames are forwarded one hop at a time toward the destination.

Bridges can be either remote or local. Local bridges provide direct connections between many LAN segments in the same area. Remote bridges connect LAN segments in different areas, usually over telecommunication lines.

Comment: hi Ron, 

the below VLANS are at building 1 with the 2621 Router

FastEthernet0/0.2 172.16.0.129
FastEthernet0/0.3 172.16.1.1
FastEthernet0/0.4 172.16.1.129
FastEthernet0/0.5 172.16.2.1
FastEthernet0/0.6 172.16.2.129
FastEthernet0/0.7 172.16.3.1
FastEthernet0/0.8 172.16.3.129

and the remaining VLANS are at the other building connected to the 2620 router, would bridging still work in this case, as the servers are currently located in building one and building two will be accessing these

Comment: I understood your question to say that you had identical subnets at each building.  I this case, IRB would work.  In any case, each subnet requires a default gateway in order to reach other subnets.  In your case, since you have several privately addressed subnets deployed already, your easiest design is to route between buildings.  Simply assign subnets per building/floor/closet.  That's how 99% of people do it.  And simply use /24 subnet masks.  Avoid the /25.  It's just easier.  KISS principle.

Answer (score 0):

Routing need to be configured on both routers . As per your requirement static routing need to configured on both routes ensuring routing between both sites .

Further make sure that both sites IP address  subnets are not conflicting.